# Using GCM to silently pass data to Phonegap application

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging

i built an application with Phonegap for Android.
Since the GCM notification doesn t satisfy my needs, i would like to call the notification from my app function.

Right now i am able to pass a GCM notification to my device.
On click on the notification, i get redirected to my application and from there on i can handle the received GCM data and built my own notification.

So right now i am looking for a way, to disable the GCM notification to the user and pass the data directly to my app to call the notification from there.
Is that even possible?

best regards,
Silent Corner

Comment: Please provide code snippets and actions taken in solving this problem. Not sure how it's done in Phonegap, but in pure Android there is a BroadcastReceiver class that receives messages from your GCM server. It is from this BroadcastReceiver that a notification is called. You can customize your app's behavior there.

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing. But i believe will have to modify the existing java doc in the push plugins.